For Regressor Problem What are the possible alternative solutions of accuracy?
Which one is the best one or if we want to define an order how we can define these
Mean Square Error
Mean Absolute Error
Root Mean Square Error
R^2 value
further do you have some ideas to plot graph to represent the model performance and accuracy of the regressor models. Is there any latest affective method .
Which one is the most useful and affective way in regressor problems

MSE-  Mean Square Error
MAE-  Mean Absolute Error
RMSE-Root Mean Square Error
R^2-   Value
